# Find all primes p for which 7 is quadratic residue mod p

Tags: number-theory

What I have done so far is that (7/p)=(-1)¤3(p-1)/2 .(p/7)
 Then i have found that (p/7)=1 if p is congruent to 1,2 ,4 mod 7 and (p/7)= -1 if p is congruent to 3 ,5 ,6 mod 7

AND (-1)¤3(p-1)/2 = 1 if p is congruent to 1 mod 4 and -1 if p is congruent to 3 mod 4 ...

NOW how i must proceed to determine all primes mod 28 for which 7 is quadratic residue mod p ? 
  Any help will highly be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You need to solve six Chinese remainder theorem questions:

$$p\equiv a\pmod 4\\p\equiv b\pmod 7$$

where $(a,b)$ is is each of $(1,1),(1,2),(1,4),(3,3),(3,5),(3,6)$.

There's a simple way to do this en masse, by solving $7\cdot (-1)+ 4\cdot2=1$, so the solution to the above equation is $-7a+8b\pmod{28}$.

Of course since $-1$ is not a square modulo $7$ and $3\equiv -1\pmod 4$, you can see this collection as:

$$(a,b)=(1,1),(1,2),(1,4),(-1,-1),(-1,-2),(-1,-4)$$

So you can just compute the results for $(1,1),(1,2),(1,4)$, and take the negatives for the other cases.

And you need to deal with the case of $p=7$ separately.